# Python class __add__ method with number as first operand

Tags: python

I need to write python class that can add with integers. I came up with following class.

```py
class N:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, b):
        return self.val + b


print(N(1) + 5) #success, return 6
print(5 + N(1)) # raise error, unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'N'
```

Is there a way to make this work for both `N(1) + 5` and `5 + N(1)`?

Comment: Define [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) as well.